# WSL2 crashed (docker backend and Ubuntu), now Ubuntu starts into root instead of my user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, zsh, wsl2

Any WSL2 instances stopped responding to anything, so I ran `wsl --shutdown` in CMD and restarted the instances. Since then, my Ubuntu instance starts as `root` instead of my user `hardya`. This happens if I go in via CMD or start a Ubuntu session directly. I use zsh if that has anything to do with it?

I'm at a loss as to why this keeps happening.

```
C:\Users\hardya>wsl --status
Default Distribution: Ubuntu
Default Version: 2

Windows Subsystem for Linux was last updated on 12/05/2022
WSL automatic updates are on.

Kernel version: 5.10.102.1
C:\Users\hardya>wsl
➜  hardya whoami
root
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't explain what happened when WSL crashed, but you can
at least reset your default user.

If you have only one distribution installed in WSL,
run at the Windows Command Prompt this command :

```
ubuntu config --default-user <username>
```

For multiple distributions, see the reference below.

Reference :
[How to change default user in WSL Ubuntu bash on Windows 10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/816732/how-to-change-default-user-in-wsl-ubuntu-bash-on-windows-10).

Comment: That did the trick. No idea what caused it either